# Does jQuery's $.getScript behave differently in Firefox ? It's not executing the script after loading it, Chrome is doing fine

Tags: jquery, dygraphs, jquery-get

The following code

```
$.getScript("/js/dygraph-combined.js")
  .done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log(Dygraph);
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.error('it failed to load');
  });
```

yields

> Dygraph is not defined

in Firefox 11.0, and

> [Dygraph 1.2]

on Chrome 17.0.963.83.

So it seems that the script loads on both browsers but doesn't get executed in Firefox 11... Why would that be ? How do I get this behaving like it should ?

This script is [Dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/) and from it's website it works on Firefox, but my graphs only work on Chrome possibly because jQuery's $.getScript might be behaving differently...

Comment: What URL are you testing at? It could be a relatively absolute path issue.

Comment: I'm testing at /#!/admin... But /js/dygraph-combined.js actually exists and there's no 404 error in the logs. It does actually load the file, I can see it in Firefox's console with Ctrl+Shift+K... I think it's just not executing the script... If I put inside "console.log(script)" inside the callback of .done, it will print out the code of that script, both in Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: Can you post dygraph-combined.js?

Comment: @Adam here it is: http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo - Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
    $.getScript("http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js", function(script, textStatus) {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(Dygraph);}, 0);
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.error('it failed to load');
    });
```

Comment: With 0 it yields the same result as before, but if I wait 700ms it does display the graph... is it weird that it works so fine in Chrome but not in firefox ?

Comment: Update: But only because I was loading from http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js.... Now that I'm loading from the same server, with /js/dygraph-combined.js that I swear it exists and doesn't give a 404 error, it just won't happen...

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem would be, it works fine for me in ff and chrome, maybe it just needs to propagate throughout the cache before? But i means as long as it works like that lol

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo Are you sure that the path is correct? and can you post a link to the one on your sever?

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox and Chrome but in Dygraphs' website, most probably because they're not using $.getScript to load the library. Yes, I'm pretty sure the path is correct, as I said I see the file being loaded in the console... Well I can give you a link but you'd have to register and then login because it's in an administration page... http://crowdprocess.com and when you register, log in to http://crowdprocess.com/#!/admin

Comment: For what it's worth, you shouldn't source directly from dygraphs.com as that file tends to change frequently and without warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in the dygraph-combined.js it said "This is not the file you are looking for". but the jedi mind trick didn't work on me, I followed the link provided.
http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js

Now it works :)